# summation of infinite terms contradiction

Tags: sequences-and-series, inverse-function

Consider the sum $$\sum_{i=0}^\infty (\tan^{-1}{(i+1)} - \tan^{-1}(i))$$
if we write $n^{th}$ terms ($T_n$)
$$\begin{align}
T_0 &= \tan^{-1}(1) - \tan^{-1}(0)\\
T_1 &= \tan^{-1}(2) - \tan^{-1}(1)\\
&\ \vdots\\
T_n &= \tan^{-1}(n+1) - \tan^{-1}(n)
\end{align}$$
since we are adding to infinity, so all terms must cancel. whatever term we can think of will be cancelled by successive term.

so
$$\sum_{i=0}^n (\tan^{-1}{(i+1)} - \tan^{-1}(i)) =  - \tan^{-1}0 = 0$$

#### BUT

if we add all above terms, you can notice that terms start cancelling each other.
so,
$$\sum_{i=0}^n (\tan^{-1}{(i+1)} - \tan^{-1}(i)) = \tan^{-1}(n+1) - \tan^{-1}0$$

as $n$ tends to infinity
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^\infty (\tan^{-1}{(i+1)} - \tan^{-1}(i)) &= \pi/2 - 0 \\
&= \pi/2
\end{align}$$

which sum is correct and why?

Comment: $\sum_{i=0}^n{\tan^{-1}{(i+1)} - \tan^{-1}(i)} =  - \tan^{-1}0 $ is wrong. The second approach is correct.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series). The cancellation of terms you noticed gives
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\tan^{-1}(k+1)-\tan^{-1}(k)\right)=\tan^{-1}(n+1)-\tan^{-1}(0)
$$
Then note that the limit at $\infty$ is *not* $0$:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\tan^{-1}(k+1)-\tan^{-1}(k)\right)
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\tan^{-1}(k+1)-\tan^{-1}(k)\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\tan^{-1}(n+1)-\tan^{-1}(0)\right)\\
&=\frac\pi2
\end{align}
$$
You can only drop the tail terms when the limit at $\infty$ is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Sum will be $\pi/2$.

If you add, $$\lim_{n\to \infty}T_0 + T_1 + T_2 + ... T_n$$

you will get:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\underbrace{ \tan^{-1}(1) - \tan^{-1}(0)}_{ T_0}+ ... + \underbrace{\tan^{-1}(n) - \tan^{-1}(n-1)}_{ T_{n-1}} +\underbrace{ \tan^{-1}(n + 1) - \tan^{-1}(n)}_{ T_n}$$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\tan^{-1}(n+1) - \tan^{-1}(0) = \pi/2$$